# Keep program running on droplet

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, ubuntu

I've created a simple program in python3 with selenium to monitor a website. The program works as intended when I run it on my own computer, but as I need to keep it running 24/7, I've put it on a droplet from digital ocean. The program works when I am connected to via ssh, but from the log file I can tell that the program stops as soon as I close the connection. I'm guessing it has something that the problem is that the program is running on the same thread as the connection. My question is: How do I make sure the program runs in the background so it will keep running even after I close the coonection to the droplet?

Comment: You should start your program as a service. Check documentation for your OS init system (init.d/systemd). Or you can just use multiplexer such as screen or tmux. Multiplexer keeps your session running when you close the connection.

Comment: You can using `nohup python yourscript.py`. This will start the script in background and it won't disconnect when the SSH connection ends

Answer (score 0):

Try using **screen**.

It allows you to run programs in separate windows so they run completely independent from each other, and also should keep your program running while not connected.

More info about screen: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/